# How to ensure a file is not in use before using mv command?

Tags: java, file, unix

I am writing to a file `abc.txt` using a Java program, and periodically I want to move that file to a different location.

I have created a job for the same, which runs every 15 mins and does:

```
 mv oldlocation\abc.txt newlocation\abc.txt
```

How can I ensure the file is not in use by the java program before I run the `mv` command?

Comment: Make your java program create a dummy file when it starts working on abc.txt and deletes it when finished. Before running `mv` check whether that file exists. If it doesn't, your java program is not working with the file and you can move it. (This is not bullet-proof but could be close enough)

Comment: Run `lsof` on it?

Comment: The method you use in your cron will overwrite the content of `abc.txt` every 15 minutes.  If you want to keep the entire content, you could use `cp` instead.  As the file grows, you copy its entire content to the new location.